# I need a MySql table column which need to reset to starting value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am in need of a Mysql Column which will contain values in a certain range. For example, I have a column name called "apiCallCount" value of this column should within a range of 1 to 1000. Also, we needed to make this column as auto incremented(please note the table has a primary key which is auto incremented)

That is, the value of the column("apiCallCount") will be "1" when you insert the first row, it should continue to increment till 1000 as each insertion happen. Next insertion after the value become 1000 should create a row with the value "1" in "apiCallCount" column.

Comment: ok, so what is your _specific programming related problem?_

Comment: This particular mechanism is already in place with PostgresSql, I just need to migrate it to MySql. In PostgresSql it is implemented using sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Honourable Dipu, try to use RANGE_MAX column assign it to the number that you wish to be the maximum (which is 1000 according to you query) then make the field to auto increment while you are creating you database.

Comment: We have a key which already in "auto_increment" type based on MySql documentation we can't add more than one "auto_increment" per table.